# iPhone dev: Replace uppercase characters in NSString with space and downcase

Tags: iphone, regex, string, replace, nsstring

I have:

```
NSString *promise = @"thereAreOtherWorldsThanThese";
```

which I'm trying to transform into the string:

```
@"There are other worlds than these"
```

I'm guessing this is a regex job, but I'm very new to Objective C, and have so far had no luck. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `GTMRegex` (http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/), for example:

```
NSString *promise = @"thereAreOtherWorldsThanThese";
GTMRegex *regex = [GTMRegex regexWithPattern:@"([A-Z])"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:promise
                     withReplacement:@" \\1"] lowercaseString]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for removing the uppercase letters you can simply use `lowercaseString` on `NSString`.

But as for inserting spaces just before an uppercase letter, I would agree that it would be a job for a regex, and sadly, my regex fu is rubbish :)

Answer (score 0):

Without using any libraries you can use this NSString category I posted. Just perform lowerCaseString on the string array.
[How do I convert an NSString from CamelCase to TitleCase, 'playerName' into 'Player Name'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589698/cocoa-convert-string-playername-into-player-name/11813396#11813396)